# UIView for Table View Header Width Wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a UIView as my tableview header but the width is slightly smaller than the simulator for some reason. I haven't been able to fix this. The tableview is inside of a view controller and the UIView has been allocated like this:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40.0)];
```

The width is showing 375 instead of 400 as it is supposed to be so it is slightly smaller in the iPhone 6 simulator and on my iPhone 6.

[image: Here is the image of the UIView headers.]

I know the width of the iPhone 6 itself is 375, but if you see the view's width in the size inspector it says 400 as you can see in the image below. Also you can see how the UIView is slightly smaller than the UITableView width. This could be due to some spacing issue also, I am not sure. The constraints added to the uitableview were 0 spacing on the top and bottom and -20 on the left and right.

[image: Width in Size Inspector]

Comment: `self.view.frame.size.width` should be 375 on iPhone 6, how comes 400?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your frame in:

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Because in it frame is correct.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which frame would I use exactly then? self.view.frame.size.width is still 375 inside of viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Screen size of iPhone 6 is 375. Do you men 6 plus?

Comment: you can try uncheck contraint to margin when add constrian on storyboard and set myViewFrame.width = tableview.width

Comment: Bingo, I had a feeling it was the -20 spacing. I unchecked constrain to margin and the spacing option allowed for 0 which is what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a feeling it was the -20 spacing that I had on my tableview. I wasn't sure how to make it 0, but walk_alone suggested unchecking constrain to margins and this allowed me to set the spacing to 0 for both of the side constraints. This allowed for the UIView to take up the full width.